# How to repair and prevent holes in cowl panel

Tags: honda, rust

My 2009 Honda City S MT developed a leak in the roof ~10 days ago. The service station came back with the attached photos of rust on cowl panel and roof.

[image: Holes in cowl panel]
[image: Holes in roof]

I am being quoted upwards of 100k INR to replace the cowl panel below and repair by welding a new metal strip on the roof. This will involve taking down both front and rear glasses and repainting the roof and entire front of the car.

Additionally, they are also offering a ~40k package to strip the car down to bare metal and then doing an anti-rust treatment and repainting the car (including removal of the various panel dents etc).

Questions:

1. How rampant is the rust, roof leakage in Honda City?
2. Has anybody had Honda strip down their City to metal and repainted?
3. Does the car fit back together again? I.e. How much rattles and squeaks are there in a refitted Honda City?
4. Given ~7 year old car, does it make sense to do a strip down and repaint? (expect to keep the car another 3-4 years).
5. What is the best way to prevent recurrence?

Comment: Those holes below the windscreen - was that area ever cleaned of rubbish?

Comment: If the rust is that bad there I'd be concerned about the rest of the body. Whether it's worth the cost of repair depend on the value, if it's going to cost more than the car is worth don't do it

Comment: @SolarMike The area below the windscreen is usually under a largish plastic cover, so to clean it would need it to be removed completely and then washed. I don't remember a washing this detailed being done on this car. So I suppose it is 7 years of rubbish and dirt.

Comment: @GdD The photos above have been produced by a body repair expert. Per him there is only 1 more rust spot near the boot. Apart from that the car body is in good nick. The expert recommends a a full body paint though.

Comment: So, you've answered question 1 yourself, you know where the rust is already.

Comment: @GdD Sorry, meant the question as 'How many other people have faced similar roof rusting in Honda City' and not where is the rust in my car.

Comment: Just as an aside, 100K INR is roughly $1600 USD.

Comment: @SteveRacer The currency unit example below is a useful reference point. 100k INR = 1600 USD, true, the entire car is ~400K INR. So will need to spend ~25% of the car's value in repainting and repair.

Comment: @varunsangal Thank you, I agree.  That should put this in perspective.  If it were *me* (and you have to understand that I am at heart a "hillbilly" without extensive funding) I might find a way to patch it with roofing tar and whatever else to get more useful mileage out of the vehicle, while saving my money for a new vehicle in the future.  I am a very good mechanic and can fix *anything*.  However, once the cancer starts it perhaps is time to let things go and envision the next project.... But meanwhile drive drive drive and get every bit of value you can.  This is just my opinion.

Comment: @SteveRacer Am not a good enough mechanic to put a welding rod to the hole, but I get the sense of what you are saying, will try to hunt for a cheap option as budget is definitely a constraint. Need to get it fixed nonetheless as I live in a place where it rains at least 4-5 months of the year, can't have rainwater collecting in the footwell.

Answer (score 1):

I will address question 4: is it worth getting a bare metal re-spray. I'm not going to answer this directly as I don't have accurate figures, but I'll give you the approach I'd use on any car: the costs of the respray should be less than the change in resale value for doing it when you plan to sell the car.

Say a respray will cost 2000 currency units (CUs), the resale value without the respray will be 10000 CUs and the resale value with the respray will be 13000 CUs, then the respray would make financial sense. If the resale value with the respray is 11000 CUs then it wouldn't make financial sense to do it. Some cars drop some much in value over time that no amount of body work will make financial sense, with others body work is a good investment.

So if you're going to get the money back go for the respray, if not I'd personally leave it unless:

- You have some sentimental attachment to the car
- The appearance of your car is important for work or other reasons

To me 7 years is not that long for a paint job, a respray seems excessive. A good deep polish will be far cheaper and probably give a good result.

Comment: That is a great way to look at the repair job. Thanks. The respray is coming into picture as the repairing the leak would mean the entire front end to be repainted, so I will end up with ~30% car repainted at ~50% of cost. Need to keep the car as a similar new one is definitely out of budget for now.

Comment: If you look at the pictures you'll actually see two things: missing metal from rust and a missing windshield. No amount of rubbing is going to cure this or even attempt to make it look better. Your use of "currency units" is really good though. You make this explanation viable for *any currency*. Great way of looking at it.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2, I was addressing the full respray as opposed to the repair. Of course some repainting is required, this answer is about the non-rusted parts of the car.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 The windshield was taken off at the body repair shop to assess the cause of the leakage. It is stored away safely to be reinstalled later.

Comment: @varunsangal - Yes, assumed the windshield was still around. Point being, it's been removed from the vehicle.